# Leaflet Awesome Markers icon isn't display in R

Tags: r, filtering, ggmap, markers, r-leaflet

This is my data set:

```
start_stations <-
  data.frame(
    station = c("StreeterDr", "MichiganAve", "WellsSt"),
    lat = c(41.89228, 41.90096, 41.91213),
    lng = c(-87.61204,-87.62378,-87.63466),
    n = c(23000, 56780, 34520)
  )
```

This is the code I tried to plot the map using these lat and lng coordinates and add color variations to stations (locations) according to its count and label each location using name and count.

```
install.packages(c("leaflet", "sp")) 
library(leaflet)
library(sp)
install.packages("sf")
library(sf)

lon <- start_stations$lng
lat <- start_stations$lat
name <- start_stations$station
count <- start_stations$n
dfs <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon,lat,name,count))

dfs <- sf::st_as_sf(dfs, coords = c("lon","lat"), crs = 4326)

getColor <- function(dfs) {
  sapply(dfs$count, function(count) {
  if(count <= 20000) {
    "green"
  } else if(count <= 30000) {
    "orange"
  } else {
    "red"
  } })
}

icons <- awesomeIcons(
  icon = 'ios-close',
  iconColor = 'black',
  library = 'ion',
  markerColor = getColor(dfs)
)

leaflet(dfs) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(~lon, ~lat, icon=icons, popup = ~as.character(name), label=~as.character(count))
```

[image: This is the output I got]

Everything works correctly except display the icon. I want to display the icons with the color respective to the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

The information of using R in Kaggle was shared later by asker. When using Kaggle there are problems with the use of `addAwesomeMarkers`. Other markers like e.g. `addCircleMarkers` are working well.

---

As shown in the map below following code is working with following environment on Windows 10 .

- RStudio 2021.09.0 Build 351 © 2009-2021 RStudio, PBC
- newest version of packages sf and sp

```r
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# sample for awesomeIcons - color by value
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

start_stations <-
  data.frame(
    station = c("StreeterDr", "MichiganAve", "WellsSt"),
    lat = c(41.89228, 41.90096, 41.91213),
    lng = c(-87.61204,-87.62378,-87.63466),
    n = c(23000, 56780, 34520)
  )

library(leaflet)
library(sp)
library(sf)

lon <- start_stations$lng
lat <- start_stations$lat
name <- start_stations$station
count <- start_stations$n
dfs <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon,lat,name,count))

dfs <- sf::st_as_sf(dfs, coords = c("lon","lat"), crs = 4326)

# --- character to integer -----------------------------------------------------
dfs$count <- as.integer(start_stations$n) 

getColor <- function(dfs) {
  sapply(dfs$count, function(count) {
    if(count <= 25000) {
      "green"
    } else if(count <= 35000) {
      "orange"
    } else {
      "red"
    } })
}

icons <- awesomeIcons(
  icon = 'ios-close',
  iconColor = 'black',
  library = 'ion',
  markerColor = getColor(dfs)
)

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(data=dfs, ~lon, ~lat, icon=icons, popup = ~as.character(name), label=~as.character(count))
```

Please note following edited lines and some edited values in your `getColor <- function(dfs)`

```r
# --- character to integer -------------------------------------------------
dfs$count <- as.integer(start_stations$n) 

...

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(data=dfs, ~lon, ~lat, icon=icons, popup = ~as.character(name), label=~as.character(count))
```

[image]

or use another solution for your needs like this:

```r
library(dplyr) # add for use of mutate

# --- character to integer -------------------------------------------------
dfs$count <- as.integer(start_stations$n) 

# --- add color group column -----------------------------------------------
dfs <- mutate(dfs, group = cut(count, breaks = c(0, 25000, 35000, 99000, Inf),
                              labels = c("green", "darkred", "red", "purple"),  include.lowest = TRUE))
dfs

icons <- awesomeIcons(icon = "ios-close",
                      iconColor = "yellow",
                      library = "ion",
                      markerColor = dfs$group)

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(data=dfs,~lon, ~lat, icon=icons, popup = ~as.character(name), label=~as.character(count))
```

Comment: I tried both codes. But location icon isn't still appear.

Comment: @KalsaraL - see my edit (version info and `library(dplyr) # add for use of mutate)`. `library(dplyr)` is required for the mutate function. Seems something is wrong with the software you installed. Also, answers to other of your questions on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70119845/1981088) apparently didn't fully work for you.

Comment: @ help-info.de- I used Kaggle note book for execute this code. I'm also think there is a version problem not a problem of code. How can I overcome this issue. Thank You!

Comment: @help-info.de-Are there any additional library needs for icons in Leaflet Markers

Comment: @KalsaraL - AFAIK noo additional library. See my edit.

Comment: @help-info.de- When I remove "icon=icons" from addAwesomeMarkers() function, Marker icons display with the count and name but in same color. This method isn't facilitate to depict color segment.